# How do I check a checkbox in the parent frame from within an iframe's $(document).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(parent.top).find('.IAgreeCheckBox:first').prop("checked", true);  
});
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.IAgreeCheckBox:first', window.parent.document).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Like the use of `context` parameter in this situation

Comment: As a side-note, `window.parent === parent`, so unless the `parent` variable has been shadowed, it can be used directly.

Comment: It finds the checkbox, however, it doesn't check it

Comment: @Kant Are you sure it's the check-box object? Try `obj instanceof HTMLInputElement` on it.

Comment: Here's the markup for it: <input id="wOnlineApplication_cbxIAgree" name="wOnlineApplication$cbxIAgree" type="checkbox">

Comment: @Kant: Where's the IAgreeCheckBox class? :/ try `$('#wOnlineApplication_cbxIAgree', ..)` - [that should work](http://jsfiddle.net/pbysh/6C64n/show/).

Comment: The problem is that <asp:CheckBox CssClass="IAgreeCheckBox"... has to be accessed $(".IAgreeCheckBox input"). Good ol' ASP.NET wraps the checkbox control in span tags so the class is appplied to <span class="IAgreeCheckBox"><input type="checkbox"...

Answer (score 3):

You'll want the `document` object, not the `window`:

```
$(parent.document).find('.IAgreeCheckBox:first')
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/dR2e8/show/)

Comment: Just `parent.document`... `parent.top` is equivalent to `top`.

Comment: It still doesn't check the parent checkbox. The funny thing is when I alert(parent.top.document).find('.IAgreeCheckBox:first'), it comes back with [object] which means it finds the element, but it doesn't check the checkbox

Comment: @Kant: That's because `parent.top.document` exists.

Comment: Yes, the checkbox exists as well. The problem is that it's not "checking" it

Answer (score 0):

If the context approach isn't working, then try this:

```
parent.$("#wOnlineApplication_cbxIAgree").prop("checked", true);
```

That's how I reference parent elements when I'm inside an iframe page.